# Python Matplotlib update bar graph in a canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I try to update my bar graph with new values inside a function. I tried it like this:

```
    #Add a Bar Graph with Matlab
    self.f = Figure(figsize=(8,3), dpi=75)
    x = [u'A1', u'A2', u'A3', u'A4', u'A5', u'A6', u'A7']
    y = ['%', '20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%']

    self.ax = self.f.add_subplot(111)

    self.data = (20, 100, 30, 35, 27, 6)        
    self.ind = numpy.arange(6)  # the x locations for the groups
    self.width = .5

    self.ax.barh(self.ind, self.data, self.width, color="orange")

    self.ax.set_yticklabels(x, minor=False)
    self.ax.set_xticklabels(y, minor=False)     

    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=self.master)
    self.canvas.show()
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=8,column=1, columnspan=4, rowspan=1, sticky=N+W, padx=25)

def update_bar():
    self.data = (100, 100, 30, 35, 27, 100)
    self.ax.clear()´
    self.ax.barh(self.ind, self.data, self.width, color="orange")

    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=self.master)
    self.canvas.show()
```

But nothing happens. What do I have to do to update my bar graph with new values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nervermind, I got it going:

```
    #call the clear method on your axes
    self.ax.clear()        
    #plot the new data
    self.data = (100, 100, 30, 35, 27, 6)        

    self.ax.set_yticklabels(self.x, minor=False)
    self.ax.set_xticklabels(self.y, minor=False)  

    self.ax.barh(self.ind, self.data, self.width, color="green")
    #call the draw method on your canvas
    self.canvas.draw()
```